Why does Docker hang intermittently on my M1 Macbook Pro and seemingly lose all connection with my containers?
I recently had to upgrade up to Docker 4.27.0 (and later 4.27.1 and now 4.28.0) on my M1 Max Macbook Pro running Sonoma 14.4.1 , and ever since then I've had a whale of a time (pun totally intended) with containers hanging randomly, sometimes for up to a minute at a time. When this happens, I've noticed that sometimes my Container CPU usage in Docker Desktop will indicate Docker is only using 1 core (instead of the 10 I've allotted), but more often than not no usage statistics will be available at all. Instead, my usage statistics will simply say "Data unavailable at this time" which seems to imply some communication problem internally that I have been unable to track down.
Docker Desktop screenshot
I have nuked my containers, reset my Kubernetes cluster, re-installed Docker, rebooted my computer, and searched far and wide on the internet for solutions (all many times), but the problem persists. Does anyone else have this same problem or have any idea what to look into to attempt to fix it?
EDIT:
Attached are some logs that possibly seem relevant (based on searching for keywords like error):

2024-05-08 17:10:10.506227-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/fe41592505f1/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506251-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/0f9d4295584e/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506435-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/8b2fa0a9686f/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506464-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/dd5dc16841fa/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506483-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/ef88cb142fa2/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506588-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/5a3cc0ece3fa/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506639-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/d19c275556a7/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506682-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/8b2fa0a9686f/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506727-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/d62d0ab99fee/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506773-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/669566ba579e/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.506839-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.44/containers/26578a0976b0/stats?stream=0
2024-05-08 17:10:10.552264-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/a9858ca46fe4/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.552265-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/40c295dd2afe/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.552279-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/bf800b194ed6/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.553900-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/bf800b194ed6/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.553970-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/fe41592505f1/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.553998-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/fe41592505f1/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.554023-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/a183981a6fd9/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.554046-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/8b2fa0a9686f/stats?stream=0"
2024-05-08 17:10:10.554069-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Context canceled, closing connection for "/v1.44/containers/d62d0ab99fee/stats?stream=0"


and

2024-05-08 17:12:50.175277-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> POST /grpc
2024-05-08 17:12:50.175305-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> POST /grpc
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176407-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Upgrading to raw stream
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176407-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Upgrading to raw stream
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176802-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Error forwarding raw stream from dockerd: write unix <HOME>/.docker/run/docker.sock->: write: broken pipe
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176815-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Error forwarding raw stream from dockerd: write unix <HOME>/.docker/run/docker.sock->: write: broken pipe
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176834-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Error closing raw stream to client: close unix <HOME>/.docker/run/docker.sock->: shutdown: socket is not connected
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176868-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy << POST /grpc (1.604334ms)
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176901-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: Error closing raw stream to client: close unix <HOME>/.docker/run/docker.sock->: shutdown: socket is not connected
2024-05-08 17:12:50.176929-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy << POST /grpc (1.650083ms)
2024-05-08 17:12:50.181141-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:12:50.182248-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy << HEAD /_ping (1.110084ms)
2024-05-08 17:12:50.182381-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> GET /v1.43/version


as well as

2024-05-08 17:21:49.807221-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: HTTP 792 CONNECT desktop.docker.com:443: successful (30 active requests)
2024-05-08 17:21:52.644874-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: unable to inject 1 events for 20.003684292s
2024-05-08 17:21:55.502717-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:21:55.508397-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:21:57.504070-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:21:57.509710-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:02.642350-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: unable to inject 1 events for 30.001132708s
2024-05-08 17:22:09.439726-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: error copying: write unix <HOME>/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/stats.sock->: write: broken pipe
2024-05-08 17:22:10.505696-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:10.506828-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:12.506851-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:12.508024-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:12.642161-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: unable to inject 1 events for 40.000909167s
2024-05-08 17:22:22.642118-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: unable to inject 1 events for 50.000925583s
2024-05-08 17:22:24.286494-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: (cc37e6a5) 06941967-stats C<-S 20940aae-stats GET /vm/ram-cpu-usage (41.502319041s): {"cpuPercentage":93.48609680741504,"memAvailableBytes":8029368000,"memBytes":7958116000,"numCPU":10}
2024-05-08 17:22:24.286628-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: (ba924580) 06941967-stats C->S stats GET /vm/ram-cpu-usage
2024-05-08 17:22:25.526237-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:25.526350-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:27.527561-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:27.527674-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: proxy >> HEAD /_ping
2024-05-08 17:22:32.642312-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: unable to inject 1 events for 1m0.001112333s
2024-05-08 17:22:34.287815-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: (ba924580) 06941967-stats C<-S NoResponse GET /vm/ram-cpu-usage (10.001143667s): Get "http://ipc/vm/ram-cpu-usage": context deadline exceeded
2024-05-08 17:22:34.287881-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: (ba924580-1) 06941967-stats C->S stats GET /ping
2024-05-08 17:22:34.287953-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: (ba924580-1) 06941967-stats C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (72.75µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": context deadline exceeded
2024-05-08 17:22:34.287977-0400  localhost com.docker.backend[98054]: fetching stats failed, possibly because of idle: request failed and retry attempts exhausted: Get "http://ipc/vm/ram-cpu-usage": context deadline exceeded



Could you share the docker logs?

@cryptic_hash added some logs

I don't feel this answer is sufficient enough to mark as an accepted solution, but in case others come across this issue I wanted to mention that increasing the amount of memory available to Docker (Settings > Resources > Advanced > Resource Allocation > Memory Limit) from 8 GB to 32 GB seems to have resolved most of my hanging problems for now. Containers still hang occasionally, but I have not seen the "Data unavailable at this time" message under my Usage Statistics since the bump up. All I can think at this point was that my problems might have been related to memory swapping.
